# 'Central' Confirm before delete or multiple versions in JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add functionality to my current delete function. The problem I am having is when I click delete, it deletes straight away without prompting. I have been trying to add the functionality of a prompt using answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462771/confirm-before-delete).

The question I have is which is the most efficient way to implement the delete function, currently I have 4 instances which can be deleted and they all have code similar to this:

```
function removeDoom(doom) {
        doomResource.delete({ id: doom.doomId })
            .$promise
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    logger.success("Doom has been Removed", "Success");
                    $state.go("dashboard.doomPage");
                    getDooms();
                }
                else if (!response.success) {
                    logger.error("Error", response.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                vm.error = exception.catcher("Error", response);
            });
    }
```

Is implementing a delete function which can be used by all 4 of the instances a better way than having individual delete functions in the.js files? If I implemented a 'central' delete function, how does that affect the HTML side where I use the following for the button?

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" bs-tooltip="{'title':'Remove Doom'}" ng-click="vm.removeDoom(doom)"></a>
```

The reason I had implemented 4 instances is for some of them, it checks to see if there is any dependencies linked to that instance, and if true it does not delete but first throws an error stating, "Instance is being used by an Application and can't be deleted." Is it possible to implement a solution with rules to factor this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For implementing 'central' delete function you have to make one service like

```
(function() {
  angular.module('module name')
  .service('serviceName', serviceName);

  function serviceName (
     dependency which you wanted for function like $state
    ) {
    this.removeDoom = removeDoom;

    function removeDoom(doom) {
        doomResource.delete({ id: doom.doomId })
            .$promise
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    logger.success("Doom has been Removed", "Success");
                    $state.go("dashboard.doomPage");
                    getDooms();
                }
                else if (!response.success) {
                    logger.error("Error", response.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                error = exception.catcher("Error", response);
            });
    }
  }
})();
```

and for implementing prompting use uib modal take reference from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

And in that callback function write this

```
doomResource.delete({ id: doom.doomId })
            .$promise
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    logger.success("Doom has been Removed", "Success");
                    $state.go("dashboard.doomPage");
                    getDooms();
                }
                else if (!response.success) {
                    logger.error("Error", response.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                error = exception.catcher("Error", response);
            });
```

Still, if you have any query you can ask definitely.

Comment: Before it deletes, would it ask the user to confirm they want to delete? And then when would it check to see if there's dependencies, upon confirmation of delete, or before the modal saying are you sure?

Comment: Yes, Use uib modal and you can ask user are you sure you want to delete and if user press yes then it will be deleted.

we using like this 

$scope.modalInstance =
          ModalService.openModal($scope, 'Update Target', contactObject.addAsTargetMSG +
            '<br/>Are you sure you want to update target detail?', 'Yes' ,
            'Cancel', modalCallBack);

but in this we make service for modal